# Angular 7: adding mat-raised-button to button through directive

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

I have stuck with the directive. trying to add "mat-raised-button" and "color" to buttons through the custom directive. But it didn't work. please help me to work this.
the code is here,

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2, HostListener, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatRipple } from '@angular/material';
import { MatRipple } from '@angular/material';
@Directive({
    selector: '[appButton]',
    providers: [MatRipple]
})
export class ButtonDirective{
    constructor(el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer2, ripple: MatRipple) {
        renderer.setAttribute(el.nativeElement, 'mat-raised-button', '');
        renderer.setAttribute(el.nativeElement, 'color', 'primary');
    }

}
```

Comment: button tags don't have such attributes as you defined like mat-raised-button or color

Comment: You are trying to bind directive `mat-raised-button` dynamically which is not possible this way.